# How to create a factory method from json string

Tags: c++, json, constructor, factory

I would like to write a factory method that constructs C++ objects from a json string (or xml string) with the following signature:

```
BaseClass * create_class_from_json(const std::string & json_str)
```

{

If I pass the following json string, the method first determines the class is `Derived1` and call the constructor of the with the parameters provided.

```
{
'class_name':'Derived1'
'param1':10
}
```

The standard way to implement this is to have a long `if` statement on the `class_name` and construct the appropriate class in different cases:

```
BaseClass * create_class_from_json(const std::string & json_str){
    std::string class_name = json::extract_field(json_str, 'class_name');
    if (class_name == 'Derived1')
    {
      int param1 = json::extract_field(json_str, 'param1')
      return new Derived1(param1);
    }
    else if (class_name == 'Derived2')...

}
```

Is there a better / more elegant way of doing it in C++?

Comment: There is always a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no straight forward solution, but lately I've seen a nice [article which can help you solve this in quite clever way](http://www.bfilipek.com/2018/02/factory-selfregister.html).

Basically you factory must be a singleton and created object are using a template which register each type to this singleton.

This is quite similar to test in google test, which are self registering in some singleton.

Just read article for more details.

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. C++ does not have reflection.

However, you could do this instead as a preprocessing step in your build process, *outside* of C++. Have a Python script generate some C++ object declarations into a source file, that you then compile.